# How to resolve and proxy all HTTPS traffic without SSL termination using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, dns

I am creating a simple DNS server which will only resolve A records for whitelisted domain names and uses 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) to resolve un-whitelisted domains.

Whitelisted domains are resolved into a custom proxy server at `x.x.x.x`.
There is a nginx server at `x.x.x.x` that redirects all of the traffic based on the hostname provided in `Client Hello` message.

The entire flow:

1- DNS Server received query for A record `example.com`

2- `example.com` is whitelisted, so the DNS Server sends `x.x.x.x` as the Answer.

3- Client sends `Client Hello` to `x.x.x.x` as it believes it is the ip address of `example.com`

4- Nginx server extract the hostname from `Client Hello` and uses 8.8.8.8 to resolve the domain itself and then, passes the request to the original ip address of `example.com`

When using this setup and proxying every domain (so every requested domain no matter whether its whitelisted or not resolves to the ip address of nginx server located at `x.x.x.x`) some requests face trouble.

Since some connections are facing problem and some not then there has to be a problem with the TLS handshake (clients sending DNS queries are not controlled)

How the clients or the final servers are preventing this? is it related to SSL pinning?

Thanks in advance

Nginx config:

```
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log /dev/stdout debug;

http {

    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name _;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

stream {
    server {
        resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $ssl_preread_server_name:443;
    }
}
```

some logs from error_log with level of debug in nginx:

```
2022/05/21 15:25:36 [error] 6#6: *398 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying and reading from upstream, client: x, server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "x:443", bytes from/to client:696/6998, bytes from/to upstream:6998/917
2022/05/21 15:25:33 [error] 6#6: *476 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x, server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "x:443", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

Comment: *"some connections are facing problem"* - what kind of problems exactly? What kind of error messages you get in the browser, what kind of messages in the nginx log? *" is it related to SSL pinning?"* - since certificates are not changed this does not infer with certificate validation or pinning.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I added some of the error logs, please let me know if you want any specific way of reading the logs

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I forgot to add that not 100% of the clients are coming from browser

Comment: First, some clients might not use SNI so the basic idea will not work for these. Then the error logs you provide only show failed and broken connections, which is not even clear if these are the cause of the problems (such things happen all the time). You still did not provide what exact problems you actually face, only a vague *"facing problem"*

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The exact thing I am having problem with is a game launcher (riotgames league of legends to be exact) upon logging in into the launcher, the error I added comes up and the launcher closes itself.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich if the client is not including the SNI, how is the target server (which is hosted on AWS I believe) is figuring out where to redirect requests to?

Comment: Given that you base everything on SNI the target server cannot figure out the target without SNI

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have tried curling `curl https://api.ipify.org` and I received `curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed` but if I provide -k to curl (bypassing tls check) I receive the response just fine and the returned ip is the ip of the proxy server (`x.x.x.x` in the original question), with my configuration of nginx, why this happens?

Comment: Please add the verbose output of curl to your question so that one can see, what certificate it gets and where it connects to: `curl -v -k https://api.ipify.org`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sadly I am no longer receiving that error, but here is the output nonetheless,  * Connected to api.ipify.org (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: ALPN, offering http/1.1

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am logging all of the requests that the nginx is proxying, all of them include hostname in SNI (OR, nginx is silently dropping them), if the problem is not with the SNI not being present, what else could be the problem?

Comment: If the problem cannot be reproduced then there is nothing to debug and nothing to fix. The question *"what else could be the problem"* can not be answered if no problem is there anymore.